# Directory.SetCurrentDirectory with admin privileges.

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm trying to set up a work flow assistant that needs to grab files/execute commands from several different mapped network drives.

I have 3 separate mapped drives. Z:\ Y:\ and W:\ ( along with my C:\ )

When I try to do something along the lines of:

```cs
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("Z:\\xampp\\htdocs");

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

It works just fine. It will output `Z:\xampp\htdocs` just as it should.
However, If I run the exact same code again but **with admin rights**, it gives me a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` exception.

Comment: If you can, switch to UNC paths, will save you a world of hurt.

Comment: I would love to, but because im using shell extensions, it will send `Z:\whatever\` as a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because the drive is mounted only for the user that mounted it.

So administrator account doesn't see it because it doesn't exist for them.